# What is the ideal way to serialize and deserialize polymorphic entity attribute in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, java-8, jackson-databind

I have an **Entity** class with a column attribute whose type is an **abstract class**. I want to serialize (object to JSON string) while saving it in the database column and deserialize it into an abstract class (which in turn converts the string to the appropriate concrete class) when it is retrieved from the database.

Here's how I accomplished it:

**ProductEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
@Data
public class ProductEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_TYPE")
    private String productType; 

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_SPECS")
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = 
    "productType") // -------------------> Map to concrete class based on productType value
    @Convert(converter = ObjectConverter.class) // ------------> custom converter
    private ProductSpecification productSpec;
}
```

**NOTE : "PRODUCT_SPECS" database column is of JSON type.**

**ProductSpecification.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ComputerSpecification.class, name = "computer"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SpeakerSpecification.class, name = "speaker")
})
public abstract class ProductSpecification{ }
```

**ComputerSpecification.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("computer")
public class ComputerSpecification extends ProductSpecification {
String memory;
String displaySize;
String processor;

@JsonCreator
public ComputerSpecification (@JsonProperty("memory") String memory, 
                              @JsonProperty("displaysize") String displaySize,
                              @JsonProperty("processor") String processor){
    super();
    this.memory = memory;
    this.displaySize = displaySize;
    this.processor = processor;
   }
}
```

**SpeakerSpecification.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("computer")
public class SpeakerSpecification extends ProductSpecification {
String dimension;
String sensitivity;
String bassPrinciple;
String amplifierPower;

@JsonCreator
public SpeakerSpecification (@JsonProperty("sensitivity") String sensitivity, 
                              @JsonProperty("dimension") String dimension,
                              @JsonProperty("bassPrinciple") String bassPrinciple,
                              @JsonProperty("amplifierPower") String amplifierPower){
    super();
    this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    this.dimension = dimension;
    this.bassPrinciple = bassPrinciple;
    this.amplifierPower = amplifierPower;
   }
}
```

**ObjectConverter.java**

**NOTE: I am using Jackson ObjectMapper for serialization and deserialization.**

```
public class ObjectConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String>{
private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectConverter.class);
private static final ObjectMapper mapper;

static {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
}

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attributeObject) {
    if (attributeObject == null) {
        return "";
    }
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(attributeObject);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not convert to database column", e);
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbColumnValue) {
    try {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbColumnValue)) {
            return null;
        }
        return mapper.readValue(dbColumnValue, ProductSpecification.class); // ----> mapped to 
                                                                                    abstract class
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not convert to entity attribute", e);
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Request body 1:**

```
{
    "name" : "Bose Bass Module 700 - Black- Wireless, Compact Subwoofer",
    "description" : "This wireless, compact subwoofer is designed to be paired with the Bose sound 
                     bar 700 to bring music, movies, and TV to life with Deep, dramatic bass. ",
    "productSpec" : {
                       "sensitivity" : "90 dB",
                       "bassPrinciple" : "reflex",
                       "amplifierPower" : "700 watts",
                       "dimension" : "14-5/16inW x 42-13/16inH x 16-5/16inD"
                    }
}
```

This request gets saved in the database column "PRODUCT_SPECS" as :

```
{".SpeakerSpecification ":{"sensitivity" : "90 dB","bassPrinciple" : "reflex", "amplifierPower" :"700 
watts", "dimension" : "14-5/16inW x 42-13/16inH x 16-5/16inD" }}
```

Now this solution works perfectly fine. The "SpeakerSpecification " key  neither appears in the response of GET API call nor in the swagger doc. But having to store the type info in the database really bothers me.

Is there a better approach to this problem where I could avoid having the typeinfo (".SpeakerSpecification ") in the column value?